# Error : 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, stop-words

I'm playing around with a Stopword Filter 
I feed the script a path to the file that contains articles.
However I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stop2.py", line 17, in <module>
print preprocess(sentence)
File "stop2.py", line 10, in preprocess
sentence = sentence.lower()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

my code is attached below as well
any ideas as to how to pass a file as an argument

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

def preprocess(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
    filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
    return " ".join(filtered_words)

sentence = open('pathtofile')
print preprocess(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sentence = open(...)` means that sentence is an instance of `file` (returned from the `open()` method);

whereas it seems you want to have the entire contents of the file: `sentence = open(...).read()`

Comment: I understand but this trace error still persists.....Traceback (most recent call last): File "stop2.py", line 17, in <module> print preprocess(file) File "stop2.py", line 14, in preprocess return u""" """.join(f.decode('utf-8') for f in filtered_words) File "stop2.py", line 14, in <genexpr> return u""" """.join(f.decode('utf-8') for f in filtered_words) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: unexpected end of data